# Print the colname and rowname for values that meet certain condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am desperatly trying to figure out how to print out the row index and col name for specific values in my df.

I have the following df:

```
raw_data = {'first_name': [NaN, 'Molly', 'Tina', 'Jake', 'Amy'], 
        'last_name': ['Miller', 'Jacobson', 'Ali', 'Milner', 'Cooze'], 
        'age': [42, 52, NaN, 24, 73], 
        'preTestScore': [4, 24, 31, 33, 3],
        'postTestScore': [25, 94, 57, 62, 70]}

df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'age', 
'preTestScore','postTestScore'])
```

I now want to print out the index and column name for the NaN:

```
There is a missing value in row 0 for first_name.
There is a missing value in row 2 for age.
```

I have searched a lot and always found how to do something for one row.
My idea is to first create a df with False and True

```
na = df.isnull()
```

Then I want to apply some function that prints the row number and col_name for every NaN value.
I just cant figure out how to do this.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: you probably have an error: NameError: name 'NaN' is not defined?

Answer (score 4):

had to change the df a bit because of `NaN`. Replaced with `np.nan`

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
raw_data = {'first_name': [np.nan, 'Molly', 'Tina', 'Jake', 'Amy'], 
        'last_name': ['Miller', 'Jacobson', 'Ali', 'Milner', 'Cooze'], 
        'age': [42, 52, np.nan, 24, 73], 
        'preTestScore': [4, 24, 31, 33, 3],
        'postTestScore': [25, 94, 57, 62, 70]}
```

you can do this

```
dfs = df.stack(dropna = False)
[f'There is a missing value in row {i[0]} for {i[1]}' for i in dfs[dfs.isna()].index]
```

prints a list

```
['There is a missing value in row 0 for first_name',
 'There is a missing value in row 2 for age']
```

Answer (score 3):

As simple as:

```
np.where(df.isnull())
```

It returns a tuple with the row indexes, and column indexes with `NAs`, respectively.

---

Example:

```
na_idx = np.where(df.isnull())
for i,j in zip(*na_idx):
    print(f'Row {i} and column {j} ({df.columns[j]}) is NA.')
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like the below:

```py
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    nans = row[row.isna()].index
    for n in nans:
        print('row: %s, col: %s' % (i, n))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think melting is the way to go.

I'd start by creating a dataframe with columns: index, column_name, value.
Then filter column `value` by not null.
And dump the result to dict.

```
df = pd.melt(df.reset_index(), id_vars=['index'], value_vars=df.columns)
selected = df[df['value'].isnull()].drop('value', axis=1).set_index('index')
resp = selected.T.to_dict(orient='records')[0]
s = "There is a missing value in row {idx} for {col_name}."

for record in resp.items():
    idx, col_name = record
    print(s.format(idx=idx, col_name=col_name))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just create a variable
NaN = "null"
to indicate empty cell

```
import pandas as  pd

NaN = "null"
raw_data = {'first_name': [NaN, 'Molly', 'Tina', 'Jake', 'Amy'], 
        'last_name': ['Miller', 'Jacobson', 'Ali', 'Milner', 'Cooze'], 
        'age': [42, 52, NaN, 24, 73], 
        'preTestScore': [4, 24, 31, 33, 3],
        'postTestScore': [25, 94, 57, 62, 70]}

df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'age', 
'preTestScore','postTestScore'])
print(df)
```

output:

```
first_name last_name   age  preTestScore  postTestScore
0       null    Miller    42             4             25
1      Molly  Jacobson    52            24             94
2       Tina       Ali  null            31             57
3       Jake    Milner    24            33             62
4        Amy     Cooze    73             3             70
```

Comment: thats not a good idea. you would rather use nans that pandas understand... either use np.nan or float('nan')